# asp.net dataset xsd error : variable is used before it has been assigned a value

Tags: asp.net

I am using visual studio vb asp.net, i am trying to use dataset.xsd. but i am getting error.
It is showing error , that ABC variable is used before it has been assigned a value a null reference exception could result at the runtime

in my program i have loginDataSet.xsd  > uloginDS

this is the coding

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim uloginAdapter1 As New loginDataSetTableAdapters.uLoginDSTableAdapter
    Dim ds1 As loginDataSet.uLoginDSDataTable
    Dim abc As loginDataSet.uLoginDSRow
    ds1 = uloginAdapter1.GetData()

    Dim k As String = abc.uName
    txtUserPassword.Text = k

End Sub
```

This video shows how to work with dataset design and it has more parts.
it is a youtube video link.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIgKuATsb-E

But this video not shows how to read 1 row or 1 data entry.
i try some coding but getting a error

Answer (score 0):

You have never assigned a value to `abc`.

Assuming that the GetData returns only one row, you need to do

```
Dim abc As loginDataSet.uLoginDSRow
ds1 = uloginAdapter1.GetData()
abc = ds1.Rows(0)
Dim k As String = abc.uName
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you very much John. it is working now .. im trying to solve it from 3 days... thank you very much for help

Comment: `NullReferenceException` always means the same thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net.

Comment: Hello John
I want to know some info about .Fill()
What is the use of uloginAdapter1.Fill() and how to work with it , can you give me a small example of it.
thank you

Comment: @JasbirBhinder: that's a separate question. Please ask a new, _focused_ question if you want to know something specific about Fill.